# Hibernate -> n:m relation -> problem insert in a joined table

Tags: hibernate

I have a bidirectional n:m relation with two entities and I have created domain objects for using with Hibernate in the latest version 3.5.3.
I used this for my example:
http://tadtech.blogspot.com/2007/09/hibernate-annotation-many-to-many-join_03.html

My problem: The Addres will be added without a problem. But it does not make an insert on the join / link table. What's wrong here? Something wrong with cascading?

Thanks a lot in advance & Best Regards.

Comment: Show your code (not the mapped classes if they are identical, but the code that should result in an insert).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is that I have to change the mappedBy attribute to this side I want to insert something, otherwise I have to re-update the other side of the joined table one more time, so it will make an insert to the linked table.

Answer (score 0):

could you try to remove the *@JoinTable* annotation and see if it works? I assume you have all the setter/getters in the beans (if not, add them!). I believe the issue is in that fragment of code, as it has worked for me without it.

Also, I don't understand this limitation in the code you mention:

```
...
@JoinColumn(name="personId", unique = true)
...
```

To me it seems like that should be OneToMany, not ManyToMany...